# How to instantiate a prefab associated with a class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Every time i needed a prefab i would just instantiate it from my prefabs folder and yada yada everything is working perfectly.

But now im trying something different.
I have a class `Player()` wich has lets say a prop called `public int MoveSpeed{get;set;}`.
Ok now i want to instantiate a prefab `"myPlayer"` associated with my `Player` class. So i could do things like `myplayer.Movespeed = x;`

How do i use the instantiate(***in this scenario***)?
How do i use the constructor `Player myPlayer = new Player(moveSpeed = x);`

I have been searching about this in a lot of places, bue the answers were foggy to me, can anyone help me?

EDIT: I think what im trying to do has no logic. Unity works witha a Component-Model Paradigm, and im trying to go againt that it seems.
The reason why i am asking this is because this time i want to have a solide, smart and flexible code, not a spagheti code mess.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate an empty GameObject and build on it, prefabs are just shortcuts so you don't have to write tons of line of code to build up the components on gameobject, here is example:

```
GameObject someGO = new GameObject();
Player refToClass = someGO.AddComponent<Player>();
refToClass.Movespeed = x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still havent figured it out in my head.
I think ill just stick with the PlayerController.
I asked this because i didnt want to declare variables and mess around wiht user input in the same script. I'll see if i have to create 2 scripts, a class that holds var's(does not inherit from monobehaviour) and a script that handles userInput + collision.

Comment: Try what I posted, it's a good solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: I did, but didnt help me. I was searching more about the unity component-base paradigm and i think this is more of an architectural problem. I should focus on behaviours and not on scripts with lots of code.
Apreciated your help.